Cannot find execution environment for SDK Remote Python 3.10
When I'm trying to run my project in PyCharm I'm getting an error:
Cannot find execution environment for SDKRemote Python 3.10.14(ssh:/@125.78.197.232:30008/home/xxx/.conda/envs/xxx_py/bin/python3.10): Python3.10.14
(sshConfig://xxx@125.78.197.232:30008password/home/xxx/.conda/envs/xxx_py/bin/python3.10)
enter image description here
How can me solve this problem
